# How to render JSX component inside specific html div in react?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

If I have multiple divs whose are rendered from data array using array.map() method like that:

```
    import React,{ ReactDOM } from 'react'
    import { useState,useEffect,useRef } from 'react'
    import getResults from '../api/getResults'
    ...
    function Results (props){
      const [results,setResults]=useState([])
      useEffect(()=>{
      setResults(getResults(props.season))},
      [props.season])
    return (
    {results.map((elem,index)=>{
       return (            
        <div key={index} onClick={()=/*what should I do to render inside this div?*/>}>{elem}</div>
       )
        })}
        <Details/> //I want to render this jsx inside the clicked div
      )
       ........
      }
```

How to get reference of specific clicked div to **render Details jsx component inside this div**? I tried use **useRef hook** but it always return the last div.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Track the clicked element in state.  For example, consider this state value:

```
const [clickedElement, setClickedElement] = useState();
```

By default the value is `undefined`.  You can update the value to some identifier when clicking one of the elements:

```
<div key={index} onClick={() => setClickedElement(index)}>{elem}</div>
```

Now each click updates state indicating which element was clicked.

Then you can use that state value to determine what to render.  For example:

```
<div key={index} onClick={() => setClickedElement(index)}>
  {elem}
  {clickedElement === index ? <Details/> : null}
</div>
```

Basically any way you approach it, the structure is pretty much *always* the same:

1. Track information in state.
2. Events (e.g. a click event) update state.
3. UI is rendered based on state.